# How to debug iOS 14 widget in Xcode 12?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, widget

I am working on an iOS 14 widget which I would like to my existing iOS 11+ app. The whole process is quite cumbersome because it happens quite often that something does not work as expected.

For example the widget shows unexpected data, or is not rendered as expected ([e.g. as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205752)). I assume that something wents wrong when the system requests the widget and its content from my app extension. However I cannot figure out what this might be.

**Is there any way to actually debug the widget extension?** Seeing when the code is executed and how it works?

I have already tried to hook up the debugger to the widget extension (using the `Debug/Attach to process` menu in Xcode). While the process is listed there, the debugger shows no log output nor stops on breakpoints.

Using the system console to show the logs of the iOS simulator devices does not work as well. It does not matter if `print(...)` or `NSLog(...)` is used. No output reaches the console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 12: iOS 14 Widget all black in simulator. How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205752/xcode-12-ios-14-widget-all-black-in-simulator-how-to-fix)

Comment: you shouldn't re-post the same questions, duplicates are often closed pretty quickly

Comment: This is not a dublicate of the question you have linked. The linked question describes a very specific problem (widget is not rendered correctly) and ask if this is a known bug and how this can be solved. This question here is about how to debug a widget in general. Of course, knowing how to debug a widget might also help to find the source of the rendering problem, but this does not make the two questions identical...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your widget target at the top left corner of Xcode, build and run the app,
then the widget process will be able to debug and show logs.
(This example project is downloaded provided by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/building_widgets_using_widgetkit_and_swiftui)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

On the top left of Xcode->

1. Click project name, you can see a list, select **widget** name, run it
2. Click widget name, you can see a list, select **project** name, run it

Xcode: Version 12.3, iPad: iPadOS 14.3 
This works for me.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work well. I also set a breakpoint in widget-only code. And occasionally I have to Clean Build Folder and/or restart the simulator.

Answer (score 5):

Since I found no other way to debug the widget extension I wrote a logging method which adds the log output to a a file a the apps group folder:

```
static func logToFile(_ text: String) {        
    if let documentsDirectory = FileManager().containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "my.app.group.key") {
        let logFileUrl = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("log.txt")
        
        do {
            var logContent = try String(contentsOf: logFileUrl, encoding: .utf8)
            logContent = (logContent.count > 0 ? "\(text)\n\(logContent)" : text)
            try logContent.write(to: logFileUrl, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        catch {}
    }
}
```

Not the best solution but the only one I found so far.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this issue as well. Logs were not showing (or only showing sometimes) when I run my widget extension in Xcode.

After hours of debugging, the thing that fixed it for me was plugging in my actual device (iPhone 12 Pro Max) and running the widget on that physical device instead of the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Seems Xcode bug here.
Quick fix works for me is open log console manually by cmd + shift + y.
And also add breakpoints.
And then run widget to see logs.

Comment: This only works on like 1 out of 100 attempts.

Comment: Same. I tried to debug widgets on a physical device - also ran into this issue. For me it helped to restart the device and add breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling bitcode in your extensions, I've had a hard time getting logs until I do it.